# Can I dissolve antibiotics and steroids in warm water for my dog?

Tags: medicines, allergies, infections

I have been mixing antibiotics and steroids for my dog in his food, without realising that this is often mixed in hot (almost boiling) water, to make it more appealing to him. Has this neutralised the effect of the medication?

Comment: Welcome to Pets.SE! Could you provide details as to what specific medications are being given?

Comment: the one planing to answer this can take a look here https://jfoodprotection.org/doi/pdf/10.4315/0362-028X-51.6.491 common steroids can be even more sensitive to heat(i have not yet found a good source for this but i know it is so from experience)